# How to deserialize a protobuf in scala

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf serialized Object in a file generated by a Python process. I now need to deserialize this in Scala.
I dont see scala docs in official google protobuf documentation. Any references? How should i go about it.

I started looking into ScalaPB for this but getting below error. Any suggestions -

plugins.sbt file : `addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "0.99.34")

libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.10.7"`

Error - `[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.thesamet:sbt-protoc;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.99.34 [error]   Not found [error]   Not found [error]   not found: C:\Users\USER\.ivy2\local\com.thesamet\sbt-protoc\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\0.99.34\ivys\ivy.xml [error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thesamet/sbt-protoc_2.12_1.0/0.99.34/sbt-protoc-0.99.34.pom [error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.thesamet:sbt-protoc;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.99.34 [error]   Not found [error]   Not found [error]   not found: C:\Users\USER\.ivy2\local\com.thesamet\sbt-protoc\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\0.99.34\ivys\ivy.xml [error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thesamet/sbt-protoc_2.12_1.0/0.99.34/sbt-protoc-0.99.34.pom [error] Total time: 8 s, completed Jul 23, 2020, 6:41:59 PM [info] shutting down sbt server`

Answer (score 2):

You need to have access to proto files that describe message schemas of objects that are serialised in the python process. The files must be shared between projects and it is mandatory information defining the contract.

You can then use [ScalaPB](https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB) to generate corresponding case classes. These classes are autogenerated by the sbt plugin and they provide helper methods that can be used for deserialisation. Check methods `parseFrom` provided in companion objects of generated `Message` classes

Comment: Thank you Ivan! I started on ScalaPB but getting error during plugin updates. Any suggestions.

Comment: @shoukatghouse I cannot reproduce your problem. Use latest sbt and follow instructions on https://scalapb.github.io/sbt-settings.html